# simultanous read and write (stdin, stdout) in C

Tags: c, stdout, stdin, simultaneous

I'm trying to write a chat client and server and the client should be able to print the messeges from the server while also writing something on the console.

So I created a pthread that should read the user input and the main thread prints the messeges from the server. But when I type something and while typing a messege is received, the text I was typing is pushed up on the console. How can i fix that?

for example:
I'm typing "abcdef" and then when I get a messege from the server (but didn't finish typing yet) it will look like this:

abcdef[Chatuser1]:Hello

Comment: What is the expected result? To show the received message only after hitting enter?

Comment: You will need to but the tty into raw mode and refresh the screen yourself after printing a message.

Answer (score 1):

Use synchronization technique like semaphore or mutex to synchronize input and output in your multi threaded program

Answer (score 0):

I would really recommend doing something like this in a GUI with two seperate edit box elements and not in a console.

If you still want to do it in a console, you will need to do direct console buffer modification.

Every time a new output message arrives, the current input message has to be backed up so you can savely write to the console then do some custom scrolling and add the input message back again. Thread syncronisation is needed to prevent mixing of input and output in the buffer.

I think you also would not get around custom key handling, because otherwise you have no access to partialy typed input.

Comment: in console, ncurses could be a solution